# How do I read receipt data with existing paid iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storekit

I have a paid app that I'm thinking about making free with in app purchases. If I make the switch I'll need to check if the user has already paid for the app and then enable the paid features.

I think the below code should do what I need but I'm not sure how to test it. I built the app and ran it using my development provisioning profile on my device and `receitpData` is empty. So I built the app with a distribution provisioning profile and submitted it to the app store then downloaded the app using test flight but I'm still having the same problem.

How do I get the receipt data from an existing app?

Do I need to enable in-app purchases for this app to get this data?

```
NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptUrl];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>
```

Don't forget to add its delegates

```
<SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate>
```

Here's the code:

```
SKReceiptRefreshRequest* request = [[SKReceiptRefreshRequest alloc] initWithReceiptProperties:nil];
request.delegate = self;
[request start];
```

and then:

```
-(void)requestDidFinish:(SKRequest*)request{
    if([request isKindOfClass:[SKReceiptRefreshRequest class]]){
        NSLog(@"YES, You purchased this app");
    }
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"NO, you need to buy it");
}
```

Comment: I haven't crossed this bridge yet, but I will at some point. Thank you for posting this.

Comment: @TomKrones Hi. Does this solution works for you at production? As I see at production environment I get a receipt for both paid and free version of my app as well. How I can distinguish user who paid for app and who not?

Comment: @AntonVlasov I'm not sure.  I ended up not needing to do this type of check in the app.

Comment: Actually, I found a solution. I just use original app version field at the receipt so I can determinate which app version user installed first free or paid. Original app version is equal to Xcode "build" field at info.plist when user firstly get app from App Store.

Comment: @AntonVlasov: How did you parse the receipt file? I have found many tutorials for macOS, but for iOS the only ones I have found require including the openssl library. Would you mind sharing your approach?

Comment: I’m using OpenSSL library too.